# JQuery Mobile on Symbian^1 device

Tags: jquery-mobile, symbian

I want to use JQuery Mobile to create an html page.

As they told in [their site](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/), N97 can handle JQuery Mobile as B-grade. I have a 5530 XpressMusic smartphone, it has same CPU and RAM as N97 and both have Symbian^1.

But when I try to open my JQueryMobile simple html page from memory card, browser opens and then closes immediately... I mean, I can't have at least C-grade functionality of JQuery Mobile.

What is the problem? Why the mobile's default web browser closes? Why can't I have B-grade or at least C-grade experience of JQuery Mobile on my phone?

And how to solve this problem?

EDIT: another place on their website tells that my phone should get A-grade experience ([here](http://jquerymobile.com/original-graded-browser-matrix/)) - 5530 and N97 are both S60v5 phones... But what is the problem?!??

EDIT 2: I'm using the latest firmware version.

Comment: have u found out any solution for this ,i have also stuck in this stage only. i have developed app using phonegap and jquery mobile framework in android .Now i have started porting to symbian os now i have finished all the setup according to documentation when i run my app in s60 sdk 5th edition its running with C-grade experience .But my mark is to get A- grade experience as native app. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokia's browser is notoriously crap. Try Opera for Symbian.